# how to manage TFS using Ansible?

Tags: tfs, ansible

I couldn't find anywhere the possibility, which is why I'm asking here, is there anyway, Ansible manage TFS? if so, then what is the best way?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage TFS"? Are you talking about managing the installation and configuration of TFS infrastructure?

Comment: @DanielMann yes, we have release and release has set of tasks and Ansible should call the release ? Is there anyway I can call the endpoint api of TFS?

Answer (score 1):

maybe look at [uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) module ? It allows you to interract with webservices